# Lucene: DocID is too High getting Exception from IndexSearcher

Tags: lucene, indexing

i have a problem with searching in a lucene index. When accesing the index with an indexSearcher i get following:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: docID must be >= 0 and < maxDoc=1300700 (got docID=1368129)
```

Searching with Google didn't help, so i hope you can help me.

Here is how i build the index:

```
Document lineOfIndex = new Document();
lineOfIndex.add(new TextField(attributeName, Class
        .forName(attributeType).cast(valueOfEntry).toString(),
        Store.YES));
writer.addDocument(lineOfIndex);
```

The index is loaded into RAM using a RAMDirectory. And here is how i try to get a document:

```
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(indexReader);
ScoreDoc[] hits = searcher.search(toSearch, 100).scoreDocs;
//move hits in ArrayList docs
for (int i = 0; i < docs.size(); i++) {
        int docID = docs.get(i).doc;
        Document d = searcher.doc(docID,
            SearchService.fieldnamesForTableAsSet(table));
//do something with the document
}
```

The index i'm trying to read is rouhgly 100mb large.
The version of Lucene is 4.3.

Here is the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: docID must be >= 0 and < maxDoc=1300700 (got docID=1337488)
org.apache.lucene.index.BaseCompositeReader.readerIndex(BaseCompositeReader.java:182)
org.apache.lucene.index.BaseCompositeReader.document(BaseCompositeReader.java:109)
org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader.document(IndexReader.java:447)
org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.doc(IndexSearcher.java:204)
de.fh.metadatenservice.search.SearchResultList.<init>(SearchResultList.java:42)
de.fh.metadatenservice.search.SearchService.processRequest(SearchService.java:78)
de.fh.metadatenservice.controller.handlers.SearchHandler.processRequest(SearchHandler.java:19)
de.fh.metadatenservice.controller.FrontController.doGet(FrontController.java:112)
de.fh.metadatenservice.controller.FrontController.doPost(FrontController.java:136)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Any help would be very nice of you.

Thanks in advance
Fabian

Comment: Stacktrace is now in the Question.

Comment: You say in a comment to an answer that you create a new searcher somewhere, but your code does not match that. Could you update your question with the proper code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In accordance to source code of [BaseCompositeReader](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/lucene/core/src/java/org/apache/lucene/index/BaseCompositeReader.java) the maxDoc computed in protected constructor.

Perhaps after creating the `indexReader` but before calling `searcher.search()` the index was modified and therefore maxDoc became invalid..

Try to instantiate the `indexReader` immediately before this line

`IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(indexReader);`

Comment: Thank you very much! This is the solution. I opened a new IndexSearcher right before handling the Document instead of passing the old searcher from the query.